# Background image hangs when loading in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, background-image

I have an odd issue. Sometimes when I load the website I've created within IE8, my main content block loads, the background color for the entire page loads, but the background image I've declared hangs for about ten seconds before suddenly appearing.

This does not happen in FF, Chrome, Safari, or IE10. Have not tested in IE9. I've read that you should try to minimize the size of the background image, so I got it down to around 100kb.

I'm just hoping that someone could give me some insight into why IE8 would hang on loading a background image. Here are links to my page, and my CSS code. Also, keep in mind that I am using GetSimple CMS, so all of the absolute paths I'm using are on purpose as this CMS requires it.

http://expirednews.net

http://expirednews.net/theme/CornerShop/css/style.css

Picture of what is happening:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY85Q.jpg

Comment: set compatible mode as ie7

Comment: This is not a viable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that it's just taking a long time to load in.  You've got a lot of graphics there, and the background image will load last.  You might consider further delaying the slideshow, and dynamically loading the images into it after both the page has completed, and a small timeout, even 100ms should help significantly.

Another alternative, is to put the background image in an actual img tag that is hidden via css.  This should cause IE to load the background image before all the slideshow images.  A little bit hacky, but quick and dirty.